# jQuery sending the name of the selected value as empty? AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.post(
    "ajax", 
    { 
        addItem : username.val(), 
        price : price.val(), 
        desc : desc.val(), 
        thumb : thumb.val(), 
        cat : cat.find(":selected").text(), 
        id : id.val() 
    }, 
        function(data) {
            error.html(data);
        }
);
```

`$_POST['cat']` will be empty

That means `cat.find(":selected").text()` doesn't function in this case.

```
echo '<select class="field2" name="category"> 
<option>Select Category</option>';
echo $shop->loadAlLCategories();
echo '</select>';
```

What did I do wrong in this case? Why is POST cat always empty no matter what I select?

```
public function loadAlLCategories()
{
    $this->items = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
    $this->items->execute();

    while ($row = $this->items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['category_name'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your cat variable if it is not an empty object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :

```
jQuery('.field2 option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should take the value of the select

```
$('.field2').val()
```